# fputc with string and int argument? "01234"[(int)tmp_seq[j][i]]

Tags: c++, c

I saw this line of code:

```
fputc("01234"[(int)tmp_seq[j][i]], opt->fp_bfast);
```

until now I thought `fputc` get a character and put it into the output stream. 
what does this line of code does

Comment: Beleive it or not it gets a character and puts it into the output stream. It does get the character in a very unusual way, but there you go, some programmers like to show off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is indexing the string `"01234"` to choose a character by treating the string as a character array. The index is `(int)tmp_seq[j][i]`.

Presumably `(int)tmp_seq[j][i]` holds a value between `0` and `4` inclusive, otherwise there will be an array indexing out-of-bounds error.

Comment: Worth saying that '0' + (int)tmp_seq[j][i] would do exactly the same thing, in a slightly more understandable manner.

Answer (score 0):

`"01234"[(int)tmp_seq[j][i]]` is a rather hideous, inefficient way to write `'0'+tmp_seq[i][j]`...